# When are methods in UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate are called ?

Tags: ios

When are methods in UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate are called ? I put breakpoints to find that they are all begining to excute after viewdidload completely excuted. I thought all these methods get called when the tableview is being load, which means they are getting called before viewdidload. Can someone help to answer me ? Thanks in advance))))

Comment: show us where/when/how you instantiate your `tableView`. Do you do it at `viewDidLoad` time? Do you do it through storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

As per View lifecycle you should assign delegate & datasource in `loadView` method.

```
override func loadView() {
    self.tableview.delegate = self
    self.tableview.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: We are not doing it in viewdidload()?

Comment: you can do it in viewDidload() but you said you want to call before view did load so you should have to call it in loadView().

Comment: will it cause any problems ? anyway, i'll give it a try, thank you.